# Do "partial shuffles" have a name?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

Let $A$ and $B$ be two totally ordered sets. A [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling) of $A$ and $B$ is a total order on $A \sqcup B$ which restricts to the given orders of $A$ and $B$. For example a shuffle of $\{a < a' < a''\}$ with $\{b < b'\}$ is $\{a < a' < b < a'' < b'\}$.

Now consider the following situation. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three sets such that $A \sqcup B$ and $A \sqcup C$ are totally ordered, and moreover the restrictions of the two orders on $C$ are equal. A "partial shuffle" is a total order on $A \sqcup B \sqcup C$ which restricts to the given orders on $A \sqcup B$ and $A \sqcup C$.

As an example of what I mean, suppose $A = \{a,a',a''\}$, $B = \{b,b'\}$, $C = \{c,c'\}$. I order $A \sqcup B$ as $a < a' < b < a'' < b'$ and $A \sqcup C$ as $c < a < a' < a'' < c'$. Then there are two possible partial shuffles, $c < a < a' < b < a'' < b' < c'$ and $c < a < a' < b < a'' < c' < b'$.

Does this notion have a more standard name? Is there an easier way to define it?

Comment: You mean the restrictions of the order on $A$ are equal?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes. Strictly speaking this condition isn't really necessary, but then there are no partial shuffles.

Comment: I just said this because there is a small typo in your definition (you said the restrictions of the order on $C$ are equall).

Answer (score 0):

What about *amalgamated shuffle over $A$* ?